# Xcode Server: Failed to mmap after update to 10.10.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I updated my Xcode Server to 10.10.2 and the latest security release. After doing so my Xcode Bots all fail with this error:

```
Failed to mmap. Could not write data: Invalid argument (-1)
```

Of course the "Fix-It" button does not work at all. I tried to reset everything like suggested here: [Xcode Bot integration error : Failed to mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168922/xcode-bot-integration-error-failed-to-mmap)

This won't help. Any ideas how to fix this?

Bests,
Philip

Answer (score 0):

OK the reason for this is that my branch I am working on contains capital letters. D'oh!